# Help me understand how a certain sum of combinations could be transformed into a given form

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

In one of my textbooks I found the following line:
$\sum\limits_{i=0}^{10} \binom{3+100-i-1}{100-i}=
\frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{i=0}^{10} [10302 -203i + i^2]$
Until now, all the steps in this textbook were very straightforward, but here I just cannot comprehend the above step and I just don't see how to easily convert the left side of this equation into the right side. Could someone explain me this as simply as possible?
 Thank you in advance for your reply

Comment: Just develop the combinatorial number inside the sum, you will get $(102-i)(101-1)/2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The part you're missing is that they're applying the identity $$\binom{n}{k} = \binom{n}{n-k}.$$ We have

\begin{align*}\binom{102-i}{100-i} &= \binom{102-i}{102-i - (100-i)}\\
&= \binom{102-i}{2}\\ 
&= (102-i)(101-i) / 2 \\
&= (10302 - 203i + i^2)/2\end{align*}

since ${n \choose 2} = n(n-1)/2$.